# Any way to recall the file of previous cmd?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, alias

Frequently I’ll have to do some digging around to figure out what I’m doing on linux, involving quite a bit of ‘’, ‘ls -la’, ‘cd’, ‘cat’, and ‘vim’

Is there any way to quickly reuse the file/target of the previous command?

e.g. I have to look around for a file, say with ls, and when I’ve found it I’ll need to use it with a program like cat or vim. So let’s say I’ve got ‘ls -la /some/path/SomeName’ and hit , say I’ve drilled down to where this is the file I was looking for.  What I’d like to do is some kind of ‘!!’ Like when you forget to use sudo; Say I really want to use ‘cat’ but had been searching around with ‘ls’ and ‘’ - or I’ve been searching around with ‘cat’, up-arrow and continuing to refine my ‘cat /file/path/‘ and then when I’ve found what I’m looking for I’ll want to edit that file

I’d like to be able to do something like ‘cat !!’ or ‘vim !!’

Comment: Also see: https://askubuntu.com/q/304830/158442

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bash with emacs key bindings then you need to know about ESC period (aka dot aka full stop). You can also use $_

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the "history event" syntax for arguments. You mention `!!`, which repeats the whole previous command. But, you can also refer to specific arguments from that command, or *all* of them. `!^` will get you the first argument; `!$` will get you the last one (think vi commands or regular expression syntax) and `!*` will get you all of the arguments (but not the command itself).

So, after finding your file with `ls -l /etc/passwd`, you could do `cat !$` to display its contents.